# javascript array varaible on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

I am a rookie on web design. I have a problem like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

    var searchIDs = new Array();
    <% searches.forEach(function (search) { %>
    searchIDs.push('<%= search._id%>');
    console.log('<%= search._id%>');
    <% }) %>    
</script>
```

...

```
<script>
    for (var i = 0; i < searchIDs.length; i++) {
        $.get('../../tCounter', { search: searchIDs[i]}, function(data){

            console.log(data.c);
            $("#" + searchIDs[i]).append("<b>" + data.c + "</b>");
        });
    }
</script>
```

On this code, I have some divs which their ids have been generated by searchID. I want to reach different html components by search IDs. Problem here, I can get true data with get and see it with console.log(data.c); but I cant reach correct component to write the data. It always appends on same div. I am waiting for your suggestions,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the internal function runs async. The loop is finished and `i` is at the highest value when they run.

The easiest way around this is using jquery's `$.each()` like this

```
$.each(searchIDs, function(i, id) {
  $.get('../../tCounter', {
    search: id
  }, function(data) {
    console.log(data.c);
    $("#" + id).append("<b>" + data.c + "</b>");
  });
});
```